# Synchronize asynchronous communication

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have a REST service which receives some data and check the data through an ansynchronous IBM MQ request.

REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response postRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {

        String data = request.getData();

        jmsSender.send(data);

        // Now I need the response from MQ
        // String mqResponse = ...
        if (mqIsValid(mqResponse)) {
            return createValidResponse();
        }
        return createNotValidResponse();
    }
}
```

MQ sender:

```
@Service
public class JmsSender {

    public void send(String data) {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("QUEUE.TO.MQ", data);
    }

}
```

MQ receiver:

```
@Component
public class JmsReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "QUEUE.FROM.MQ, containerFactory = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        // How to pass the message to the controller?
    }

}
```

How can I wait for the right data from MQ to create the correct response in the controller?

Is it possible to use a `BlockingQueue` for this like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3857392/7090808)? In my case I have to distinguish the data. I can't just take the first data from the blocking queue.

If for example there are two REST requests simultaneously (with data: `abc` and `xyz`). How can I make sure to response the right answer not just the first answer I get from MQ?

I also can't change the MQ interface.

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve this using JMS. I had to do something simillar a few month ago, and I had to use the IBM MQ classes to achieve this. If you can use the MQ Classes, you'll have to set and use a unique correlationId to match the response with the request.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. Actually the data itself contains a unique ID which I could use to identify it. But how can I tell the REST controller to wait for an response from the MQ and pass the response to the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any suitable solution for me, I've created a simple waiting mechanism to get the data.

MqReceiver:

```
@Component
public class JmsReceiver {

    private final Lock lock;
    private final Condition containsKey;
    private final Map<String, String> responses;

    public JmsReceiver() {
        this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        this.containsKey = lock.newCondition();
        this.responses = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "QUEUE.FROM.MQ", containerFactory = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        put(getKeyFromMessage(message), message);
    }

    public String get(String key) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (!responses.containsKey(key)) {
                containsKey.await();
            }
            return responses.get(key);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void put(String key, String messagee) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            responses.put(key, messagee);
            containsKey.signalAll();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

}
```

This can be used in the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response postRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {

        String data = request.getData();

        jmsSender.send(data);

        String key = getKeyFromData(data);
        // waits until MQ sends the data
        String mqResponse = jmsReceiver.get(key);

        if (mqIsValid(mqResponse)) {
            return createValidResponse();
        }
        return createNotValidResponse();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a CountDownLatch like below.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/request")
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Response postRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {
        final CountDownLatch jmsLatch = new CountDownLatch (1);

        String data = request.getData();

        jmsSender.send(data, jmsLatch);

        try {
            latch.await();  // wait untill latch counted down to 0
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return createNotValidResponse();
        }

        return createValidResponse();
    }
}
```

Modify the send method to get the CountDownLatch from controller.

```
@Service
public class JmsSender {

    public void send(String data, final CountDownLatch jmsLatch) {
        jmsLatch.await();
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("QUEUE.TO.MQ", data);
    }

}
```

Modify the receive method to get the same CountDownLatch from controller.

```
@Component
public class JmsReceiver {

    @JmsListener(destination = "QUEUE.FROM.MQ", containerFactory = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message, final CountDownLatch jmsLatch) {
        // Pass the message to the controller
        jmsLatch.countDown();
    }

}
```

The trick here is you have to spread the same CountDownLatch instance from controller to the sender and receiver class and call the countDown method after you receive the message.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a `CountDownLatch`? Can't the same be accomplished with `Object#wait` and `Object#notify` or with a Monitor like `ReentrantLock`? And how can I be sure to get the right reply from the MQ? If e.g. two request are send to the MQ and the first MQ response is for the second request.

Comment: I have prefered `CounDownLatch` when I faced similar kind of scenario. But if we go for wait/notify approach, on which object will you use wait/notify ?

Comment: For your second question, you have to shour me your code on how you are fetching the value.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for scenario sync-async implementing request-reply pattern with jms(activemq)**

The idea of this example is working in two different services in a different jvm. The solution is tested concurrent with several instances services:

- **Service 1 (M1)** - Rest api synchronous and in some point start an
  async flow using activemq to call the second Service M2 implementing Integration Pattern [Request-Reply](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/RequestReplyJmsExample.html). You don't need to stop or wait any thread, the jms pattern implements the ack **Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE**.

  ```
  @PostMapping
  public AnyDto sendMessage(final AnyDto anyDto) {
      return routeService.send(anyDto);
  }
  public void flowOrchestation (final anyDto data) throws JMSException {
      final ObjectMessage objectMessage = composeTemplateMessage(data);
      final AnyDto responseDto = jmsMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(new ActiveMQQueue("queue.request"),
              objectMessage, AnyDto.class);
  }
  private ObjectMessage composeTemplateMessage(final AnyDto data) throws JMSException {

      jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(10000L);
      jmsMessagingTemplate.setJmsTemplate(jmsTemplate);

      Session session = jmsMessagingTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection()
              .createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

      final ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage(data);

      objectMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      objectMessage.setJMSReplyTo(new ActiveMQQueue("queue.response"));
      objectMessage.setJMSExpiration(0);
      objectMessage.setJMSDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
      return objectMessage;
  }
  ```

> Timeout and expiration can be modified depending your requeriments. 0 expiration means no time to expire.

- **Service 2 (M2)**: Just receive the message and make the response to JmsReplyTo setted on M1.

`@Component
public class Consumer implements SessionAwareMessageListener<Message> {

@Override
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.request}")
public void onMessage(Message message, Session session) throws JMSException {
    AnyDto anyDto = (AnyDto) ((ActiveMQObjectMessage) message).getObject();

        //do some stuff

        final ObjectMessage responseMessage = new ActiveMQObjectMessage();
        responseMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(message.getJMSCorrelationID());
        responseMessage.setObject(dtoModified);

        final MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
        producer.send(responseMessage); 
    }}`